# Resume timer after clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

The `clearInterval` function only stops the timer in my code, but not the actual time. After I click the `stop` button, the timer stops, but it seems like it is still running in the background. When I re-click the `start` button again, it does not resume from where it stop, but show me the actual time that has been running in the background. Please see the action in the code.

How can I really stop the timer and resume it  after I click on the `stop` button by clicking on the `start` button again?

```js
var timeBegan = new Date();

function start(){    
    started = window.setInterval(clockRunning, 10); 

}

function stop(){
    window.clearInterval(started);
 }





function clockRunning(){
 currentTime = new Date()
        , timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - timeBegan)
        , hour = timeElapsed.getUTCHours()
        , min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes()
        , sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds()
        , ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

    document.getElementById("display-area").innerHTML = 
        (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" + 
        (min > 9 ? min : "0" + min) + ":" + 
        (sec > 9 ? sec : "0" + sec) + "." + 
        (ms > 99 ? ms : ms > 9 ? "0" + ms : "00" + ms);
};

function reset(){
 window.clearInterval(started);
 running = 0;
 hour = min = sec = ms = 0;
 document.getElementById("display-area").innerHTML = "00:00:00.000";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <script src="stopwatch.js"></script>
        <style>
            #display-area { font-size: 20pt; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <output id="display-area">00:00:00.000</output>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="start-button" onClick="start()">Start</button>
            <button id="stop-button" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
            <button id="reset-button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "but it seems like it is still running in the background" --- what makes you thinking that?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you never reset `timeBegan`.  You are continuing to use the same value for the start time.

You need to set this value to the current time within `start()`, otherwise you are just using the time the page loaded as your reference time instead of the time that `start()` was last invoked.

```
var timeBegan;

function start() {
    timeBegan = new Date();
    started = window.setInterval(clockRunning, 10);
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this within `reset()`, and then a stop click followed by a start click will act more like a lap timer; you can freeze the time, but in the background it would keep counting until you click the reset button.

If you want the stop button to *pause* the timer, then at the moment you click stop you need to record the current duration somewhere.  Then in your `clockRunning()` function you would add this duration to whatever your time subtraction calculation yields.  (And, of course, `reset()` should clear out this stored duration.)

Comment: @DavidWaters Dvorak FTW.

Comment: But I want to resume from the time it left. When I put `timeBegan = new Date();` inside `start`, it restart from time-zero, I mean it does not resume from where it stops when I clicked on the `stop` button.

Comment: @Zip See the last paragraph of my answer then. When you stop the timer you need to store the current duration somewhere so you can add it back in when start is clicked next.

Comment: The last paragraph is a bit tricky for me. Wanna help out? Have been trying this for 2 hours now :(

Comment: why did you delete your last comment? I am not seeing anymore.

Comment: @Zip I didn't delete anything. One option would be to store the `timeElapsed` value, and add that to the `timeElapsed` calculation on the next go around. If I get any more specific I will basically just be rewriting all of your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your current implementation of `timeElapsed`, what you would want is to make `timeElapsed` a **sum counter** where for every call of `clockRunning`, you would add the *time difference* from the last `clockRunning` call to `timeElapsed`.

1. `start` should start/resume `clockRunning` function calls
2. `clockRunning` should add to `timeElapsed` the time difference from the last `clockRunning` call
3. `stop` should stop `clockRunning` function calls, and set the `clockRunning` call time to something like `null` or `-1`.
4. In `start`, if the last time `clockRunning` is called is `null` or `-1` (basically, if stop was called), set the last time `clockRunning` is called to **now**.